# How can I parse string php

Tags: php, string

how can I parse this string into an array using php?.

```
[[1406906881,9.3],[1406907001,9.5],[1406907061,9.5],[1406907121,9.8],[1406907181,9.4],[1406907241,9.6],[1406907361,9.3],[1406907421,9.3],[1406907481,9.1],[1406907541,9.2],[1406907601,9],[1406907661,9],[1406907781,8.9],[1406907841,9],]
```

Comment: Where is it coming from? Narnia?

Comment: did you give it a try??

Comment: what is the normal way? the commas are a problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a trailing comma

```
[1406907661,9],[1406907781,8.9],[1406907841,9],]
                                              ^
```

Not sure if that's what you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse this using [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode) function in PHP. That string looks like json array.

Also, fix that trailing comma in the string (as mentioned by Alf).

Working example:

```
<pre>
<?php

$jsonArr = json_decode('[[1406906881,9.3],[1406907001,9.5],[1406907061,9.5],[1406907121,9.8],[1406907181,9.4],[1406907241,9.6],[1406907361,9.3],[1406907421,9.3],[1406907481,9.1],[1406907541,9.2],[1406907601,9],[1406907661,9],[1406907781,8.9],[1406907841,9]]');

print_r($jsonArr);

?>
```

Outputs:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work, the json_decode doen't decode the string

Comment: did you fix the trailing comma as mentioned by `Alf` - see post below